# Change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using Datepicker for my HTML field . 
The HTML code is :

```
<input type="text" id="from-datepicker"/>
```

The Jquery code to set and get the date picker fields is :

```
 $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
            $("#from-datepicker").on("change", function () {
                var fromdate = $(this).val();
                alert(fromdate);
            });
```

This code, however, displays the field in `'mm-dd-yyyy'` format. 
Can someone tell me where am I going wrong ?

My imported CDNs are :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, change dateFormat to just format and you need 4 sets of 'y's

Sample code:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({ 
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    $("#from-datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var fromdate = $(this).val();
        alert(fromdate);
    });
}); 
</script>
<input type="text" id="from-datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jason. 
That was crisp and upto the point.

Answer (score 4):

See the `format` option: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

toDisplay: function (date, format, language) to convert date object to string, that will be stored in input field
toValue: function (date, format, language) to convert string object to date, that will be used in date selection

Comment: Hi @BrOrlandi , 
Thank you. But I am not able to understand how shall I convert these value. I don't want to just save it but convert and store it in yyyy-mm-dd format. Can you please tell me how this is going to work in my code ?

Comment: @nerd.post sounds like something you could do server side

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2018**

As of bootstrap-datepicker version 1.6.4, setting `data-date-format` attribute to 'yyyy-mm-dd' on an input element works as well.

For e.g.

```
  <input data-provide="datepicker" name="date_selected" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="Select date" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

The option is `format`

You can set a default value for all your app:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'yy-mm-dd';
```

Or:

```
$("#from-datepicker").datepicker({format: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```